# C#. Для чего нужны и в каких ситуациях применяются приватные конструкторы?

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование, конструктор, инкапсуляция

Для чего нужны и в каких ситуациях применяются приватные конструкторы?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. При использовании фабрик классов:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
       private static Dictionary<object, MyClass> cache =
           new Dictionary<object, MyClass>();

       private MyClass() {
       }

       public static MyClass GetInstance(object data) {
           MyClass output;

           if (!cache.TryGetValue(data, out output))
               cache.Add(data, output = new MyClass());

           return output;
       }
   }
   ```
2. За приватным конструктором скрыть какую-то базовую инициализацию:

   ```
   public abstract class BaseClass {
       private BaseClass() {
           // здесь какая-то базовая инициализация
           // этот конструктор должен быть вызван из конструкторов дочерних классов
       }

       public class SubClass1 : BaseClass {
           public SubClass1() : base() { }
       }

       public class SubClass2 : BaseClass {
           public SubClass2() : base() { }
       }
   }
   ```

   Дочерние классы должны вызвать конструктор базового класса, где происходит инициализация базовая.

В общем и целом, как правило, приватные конструкторы используют для предотвращения создания объекта класса из вне (используется в синглтонах, фабриках и т.п).

Comment: Хм, а второй пример вообще скомпилируется?

Comment: @Андрей а почему нет?

Comment: У дочернего класса нет доступа к private-элементам родительского, только к protected

Comment: @Андрей это если бы классы были определены вне блока базового класса. В моём ответе оба дочерних класса в блоке родителя, у них есть доступ к приватному конструктору.

Comment: Ах, они у вас nested, уже увидел

Answer (score 8):

Приватный конструктор применяется, понятно, для случаев, когда вы не хотите, чтобы он был доступен снаружи.

Например, у вас может быть клонирующий конструктор, который создаёт объект из значений его полей. Поскольку вы не хотите показывать всему миру поля, то вы прячете этот конструктор, и вызываете его в методе `Clone()`.

```
class A : ICloneable
{
    int id;
    string name;
    static Random random = new Random();
    public A(string name) { this.id = random.Next(); this.name = "name #" + this.id; }
    pulbic object Clone() { return new A(id, name); }
    private A(int id, string name) { this.id = id; this.name = name; }
}
```

Или например, вы хотите, чтобы у вас контролируемое количество объектов. Например, объект — это ось координат, и вам нужно, чтобы их было ровно три: X, Y и Z. Тогда вы прячете конструктор, и выставляете готовые объекты:

```
class Axis
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Vector Direction { get; }
    private Axis(string name, Vector direction) { Name = name; Direction = direction; }
    static public readonly Axis X = new Axis("X", new Vector(1, 0, 0);
    static public readonly Axis Y = new Axis("Y", new Vector(0, 1, 0);
    static public readonly Axis Z = new Axis("Z", new Vector(0, 0, 1);
}
```

Ещё пример: у вас есть несколько конструкторов с одинаковой сигнатурой. Как быть? Добавить [фиктивный параметр](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) и заставлять пользователя догадаться, какой из них что значит? Лучшее решение — спрятать конструктор, и использовать статические методы:

```
class Point
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    public double R { get; }
    public double Phi { get; }
    private Point(double x, double y, double r, double phi)
    {
        X = x; Y = y; R = r; Phi = phi;
    }
    public static Point FromCartesian(double x, double y)
    {
        double r = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double phi = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        return new Point(x, y, r, phi);
    }
    public static Point FromPolar(double r, double phi)
    {
        double x = r * Math.Cos(phi);
        double yx = r * Math.Sin(phi);
        return new Point(x, y, r, phi);
    }
}
```

Или у вас создание объекта асинхронно, потому что вам необходимо совершить асинхронную операцию в нём. Вы снова-таки выносите асинхронную операцию в статическую функцию, а конструктор делаете приватным:

```
class Transmitter
{
    public static async Task<Transmitter> Create(IPAddress addr, int port)
    {
        var t = new Transmitter();
        await t.client.ConnectAsync(addr, port);
        return t;
    }
    private Transmitter() { } // не доступно снаружи
    private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
}
```

Comment: круто, спасибо за развёрнутый ответ с примерами, много интересного узнал. Единственный момент - у вас в последнем примере методы не статические

Comment: @Ustin: Спасибо, что заметили! :) Исправил пример.